# Change cell shade when original value is altered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create a shared Excel document (2010) whereby I create a document with data, send it around to colluegues and if they change a cell, that cell will change shade. The idea here is the spreadsheet will be large and with a lot rows and columns. The changed information will need to be keyed into a larger spreadsheet so I want to be able to quickly identify any changed data.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use the [change tracking](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-HP010197381.aspx) feature built in Microsoft Excel?

> How change tracking works
>
> Change tracking is available only in shared workbooks. In fact, when
>   you turn on change tracking, the workbook automatically becomes a
>   shared workbook. Although a shared workbook is typically stored in a
>   location where other users can access it, you can also track changes
>   in a local copy of a shared workbook.
>
> When changes are made in the shared workbook, you can view the change
>   history directly on the worksheet or on a separate history worksheet.
>   Either way, you can instantly review the details of each change. For
>   example, you can see who made the change, what type of change was
>   made, when it was made, what cells were affected, and what data was
>   added or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To do it without Excel features, in a compatible way, you will have to create a copy of list with reference values.